# Input raw JSON into JSON object from user input

Tags: javascript, json

So I have the following object that I have in javscript to send as a JSON object:

```
var authMessage = {
        MessageType: "authRequest",
        Payload: {"ClientAuthString": "abcdefg"}
}
ws.send(JSON.stringify(authMessage))
```

This code works great, does exactly what I need... now I want to accept user input (via web form) to generate this object.  I can't seem to accomplish this in javascript.

```
messageType = document.getElementById("messageType").value
payload = document.getElementById("payloadInput").value
```

Getting the messageType works fine as a string, but I want the user to enter RAW JSON into the payload and then put that into the javascript object... something like this:

```
    var message = {
        MessageType: messageType,
        Payload: payload

    }
```

So in the input field the user would enter:

```
{"ClientAuthString": "eyJhbGuuN0jcY"}
```

Then I would take that input in and attempt to send it... however this is what I get after it has been stringified..  I've tried a few different methods but was not able to send the Payload as a JSON formatted object... any ideas?

```
{"MessageType":"authRequest","Payload":"{\"ClientAuthString\": \"eyJhbGuuN0jcY\"}"}
```

Comment: "raw JSON" ... like, JSON, right? "JSON object" ... like javascript object that has nothing to do with JSON except for its origins, right?

Comment: Share the methods you've tried!  To me, not knowing what you've tried already, I would suggest using `payload = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("payloadInput").value)`

Comment: @tehhowch Yes, apparently I tried everything except the extremely obvious way, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to create the object,

```
var message = {
    MessageType: messageType,
    Payload: JSON.parse(payload)

}
```

This would parse your payload into an object and create message object, then you can stringify this.

Answer (score 1):

Think to simply `JSON.parse` should do the work:

```js
// DOM input value
var inputText = '{"ClientAuthString": "eyJhbGuuN0jcY"}';

var message = {
    MessageType: "authRequest",
    Payload: JSON.parse(inputText)
};
console.log(message);
```

Read more about [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it parses it to json

> Payload: JSON.parse(payload)